# how to change prompt of zle widgets (history-incremental-backward-search)?

Tags: zsh, zle

Is there a way to change the prompt of zle widgets such as history-incremental-backward-search?

For instance I wonder if we can colorize "bck-i-search:" or change the string, or colorize the search entries...

Thanks